# Render data from JSON ReactJS: Data not displaying as columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

I am working on building a web application using reactJS. We should display the product users subscribed to in a table form. For Example, here is the response :

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
          "user": "user1",
          "subscriptions": [
          {
             " productid":1,
             " productname":"user1_product_1",
           "productIdvalue" : 20
          }, {
            " productid":2,
            " productname":"user1_product_2",
          "productIdvalue" : 25
         }]
        },
        {
            "user": "user2",
            "subscriptions": [
                {
                    " productid":1,
                    " productname":"user2_product_1",
                  "productIdvalue" : 20
                 }, {
                    " productid":2,
                    " productname":"user2_product_2",
                  "productIdvalue" : 30
                 }, {
                    " productid":3,
                    " productname":"user2_product_3",
                  "productIdvalue" : 20
                 }, {
                    " productid":4,
                    " productname":"user2_product_4",
                  "productIdvalue" : 20
                 }]
        }
      ]
}
```

So, the subscription data is dynamic. How can I display the above data in tabular data as follow :[Mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COOnC.jpg)  User can subscribe to any number of products. As of now we don't have users who subscribed to more than 4 products.

I implemented the code as below :

```
class Example2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
      <table>
            <div>
                {
                    data.data.map((data, i) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                  {data.subscriptions.map(function (subscription, i) { 
                                                return <div key={i}>
                          <td>{subscription.productname}</td>
                          <td>{subscription.productIdvalue}</td>
                                                </div>
                                            })}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
            </table>
        );
    }
} 
export default Example2;
```

With the above code, each 'td' is getting displayed on a new line. Please let me know how to correct my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main problems:

1. Correct your data

```
" productid":1,                   // start with space, try to remove it
" productname":"user1_product_1", // like above
"productIdvalue" : 20
```

When your object keys are not right, you can not render dom by key.

2. Do not add `<div>` between `<tr>`

```
<tr key={i}>
  {data.subscriptions.map(function (subscription, i) { 
    return <div key={i}> // change <div> to <React.Fragment key={i}>
      <td>{subscription.productname}</td>
      <td>{subscription.productIdvalue}</td>
    </div>               // change </div> to </React.Fragment>
   })}
</tr>
```

[codesandbox for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-snow-61ppn?file=/src/App.js)